# How to Tag or Metadata Image Files Across Mac and PC

Tags: image, macos, tags, metadata, organization

someone asked a similar question a few years ago, but I need some additional detail.

I'm looking to build out a searchable image library for my company. We have thousands of images and I'm trying to find the best way to "tag them" so-to-speak. The images are stored on a network drive and accessed by both Mac and Windows users. I work on a Mac and have Adobe Bridge, but not everyone accessing these images will. I've seen that in Windows, you can add tags to files for searching, and in OS X, you can add Spotlight comments (delimited by commas, it can be used as search tags), however, the 2 don't carry over across platforms.

Is there anything out there that may help in accomplishing this goal?

I'm not sure how XML works. If I apply tags in Bridge or another software, will these tags be available to everyone, on whatever platform, if they are using a software that can read them? How does this work? Do they simply open the folder in one of those programs and have the ability to search and filter?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What format are they? JPEG? TIFF? PNG? NEF? CR2?

Comment: Any and all. We want the capability to tag any format. But, they are mostly JPEGs, and I would be happy with just that solution!

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid I don't have a panacea for all file formats (JPG/PNG/TIFF etc) across all OSes (macOS, Linux, Windows) across disparate application software (Photoshop/Lightroom/GIMP and MS-Paint or whatever Microsoft's offering is). However, if I put what I know, maybe someone else will know better and tell us so! Or maybe someone will know some better solutions for some pieces of the puzzle. So, in that vein...

If you have, know and love Adobe Bridge and you are *"The Keeper"* of the data, I would input, manage and control all metadata through that.

Then I believe you will need to find a way to do a nightly/weekly automated distribution of that data in a format intelligible to the *"users"* of the data. So, you will need to achieve the following:

1. Schedule an export from Bridge - my idea would be OSX's `launchd`
2. Export metadata from Adobe Bridge - my idea would be `Adobe Extendscript`
3. At this point I am thinking I would want to go with the easiest to parse, probably CSV (Comma Separated Values)
4. Now you have the info and will have to look at what your client users are using for application software and OS, and generate something intelligible to them from the CSV. I am thinking of tools like `jhead`, `exiftool`, `ImageMagick` (which can insert IPTC data).

So, there's a marker in the sand... if anyone knows better - please share your knowledge!

Other possibilities that spring to mind, are `Lightroom` which is reputedly excellent with metadata handling, or a dedicated picture-searching web-based application on your Intranet that runs on a small database updated nightly from exported Bridge metadata.

I guess the nature of the users' enquiries will be pretty important in deciding a way to go....